# Adding $request->getBody() variables to $app->request->params

Tags: slim

I've just recently switched over from laravel to slim framework for a large project and am loving the flexibility of it :)

I do have one quick question. One of the best features of laravel is not having to worry about checking the scope of a variable while checking if it exists - Input::get('varname'). This works for GET, POST and JSON payloads. I see in slim framework the $request->params() only supports GET and POST variables.

Does anyone have a snippet of code that would also enable JSON payloads in this function. I know I can use $request->getBody() and json_decode that to an array, however I'd much prefer to have it all contained in the one function since I work with angularjs as the front end and have a mix of all 3 scopes.

Many thanks! 
Cheers, 
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ContentTypes middleware](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Middleware/ContentTypes.php) for that.